# Measurement of electrons positions in an orbital, thought experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, measurements, orbitals

An orbital can hold upto 2 electrons. Let's take 1s orbital of helium.

Now, we use probability density to depict where we can find the electrons in the orbital if we make measurements. Since two electrons share the same region or atleast has alot of overlapping in 1s orbital, how will the two electrons positions be if we tried measuring them in an ensemble of helium atoms?

Like will they always be as far as possible from each other? Will our measurements somehow show that the two electrons positions are correlated  in time to each other? Such that they are not too close to each other?

I can easily imagine two electrons sharing same orbitals as a wave function but once I think of measurements I can't tell how the outcome will be. I understand it will satisfy the probability density distribution but how will they will actually do it, can they appear on top of each other randomly? Or they will somehow manage to stay apart as far as possible, like their outcomes will be correlated to each other?

Hoping some experts can share their knowledge on this.

Thank you.

Comment: In a sense, the density function describing the orbirtals is the whole thing. There is nothing else than that. Heisenberg used to say that orbits of individual electrons is a meaningless concept in these cases.

Comment: "*Electrons do not orbit a nucleus in the manner of a planet orbiting a star, but instead exist as standing waves. Thus the lowest possible energy an electron can take is similar to the fundamental frequency of a wave on a string. Higher energy states are similar to harmonics of that fundamental frequency.*" [Atomic Orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Electron_properties)

Comment: @NikosM. I do not understand your comment. The OP is speaking about orbitals, not orbits, and everything he asks is consistent with standard QM.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I was referring to the OP asking for electron positions inside orbitals. If I did not misunderstand the question.

Comment: @NikosM. Orbitals, aka r-space wavefunctions, provide information about the results of possible measurements of position. If there is a 2-electron wavefunction (a doubly occupied orbital), it is meaningful to ask what the probability of finding two electrons at two given positions will be. Thal's the way I understand this question.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I disagree with that since talking about position implies it is a meaningful concept in this case which it is not. Orbitals describe electrons as standing waves as the Wikipedia link mentions. In other cases s position measurement might be meaningful but not in these cases

Comment: @NikosM. Orbitals are standing waves. They are not electrons. Measurements of the average electron positions on equally prepared states, as are measurements of electron pair correlation functions, are possible. In all these measurements, the information obtained is about average positions in the space of single electrons. Position is a perfectly measurable quantity in QM every time a space wavefunction is available.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 specific experiments designed and prepared to measure positions are perfectly possible of course in QM. But orbitals are meaningful in all cases and not only these prepared cases. As Wikipedia mentions the electron is all over the orbital and its charge is not localized in a specific position. That is what my comments meant.

Comment: @NikosM. Your statement 'In a sense, the density function describing the orbirtals is the whole thing. There is nothing else than that.'  is inaccurate. There is potential energy, kinetic energy, spin and angular momentum and correlation. These properties can only be calculated from the full wave function.

Comment: @my2cts of course, my comment was only talking about position and orbitals

Comment: @NikosM. It is difficult to make accurate statements about quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

For a doubly occupied orbital such as the Hartree-Fock ground state of He the two electrons are uncorrelated. If both electrons are detected, simultaneously or not, the position of one electron does not affect the postion of the other. A more accurate wave function has admixture of notably 2p$_x^2$, 2p$_y^2$ and 2p$_z^2$ to 1s$^2$, which represents correlation because of Coulomb repulsion. The Coulomb correlation is not very strong because on average the, q=-1e, electrons are much further from each other than from the, q=+2e, nucleus.

This means that there is a possibility to detect two electrons, having opposite spin, in the same location just like it is possible to detect one or both electrons at the position of the nucleus.

Comment: Does this mean, the electrons could be on top of each other in this orbital when measured? Im asking this since they share the orbital there is a chance that they would be at the same place right, when measured; if they are not correlated. Or if they can't be, then doesn't that mean somehow the measurements of their positions are correlated? This is my question above.

Comment: @LuffyYadav this meaninglessness about electron positions inside orbitals is what my comments tried to clear. Electrons are all over the orbitals like waves, they cannot be localized in any specific position

Comment: @LuffyYadav I edited my answer with an explicit statement on this.

Comment: @LuffyYadav The electrons are weakly correlated by Coulomb correlation, which btw is not included in the single, doubly occupied orbital wavefunction.

Comment: @my2cts what this correlation means is that the orbital as a function of two positions takes certain values in certain places. BUT this is DOES NOT mean that in these places the electrons are localized. Please make this clear.

Comment: @my2cts in other words, the electrons are localized over the whole orbital, not in any specific position of the orbital (although different positions can have different values). Plus a measurement of position detects an electron as a particle, but not inside an orbital where the electron is a standing wave.